# What is this protrusion of bricks in my wall?

Tags: walls, brick

My house was built in 1904 in St. Louis, USA. It has a brick exterior. Currently, one of the side walls has a narrow stack of bricks near the back of the house. The stack starts in the basement and goes through the second floor. It's about 9" x 20". I don't see any thing coming into or going out of it anywhere. It takes up precious space in our (too small) bathroom and (too small) kitchen.

Any ideas what it is, why its there and if it can be removed?

Comment: perhaps the remains of a chimney ... impossible to guess if it can be removed safely ... you need to ask someone that can do hands on assessment

Comment: Pictures or drawings /sketches might help a guess, but a hands on expert would be better. It may be bracing the wall in some important way. Too small for a chimney, unless 3/4 was removed and 1/4 was not...

Comment: @Ecnerwal unfortunately almost all of it is covered, so i cant imagine a picture would be helpful. i only know its brick because there is a tiny gap where i can see the brick in my basement where the floor joists are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a picture to confirm, it sounds like it may be a pilaster. If so, it is structural, and possibly helping carry a load (beam) above the ceiling

Comment: This is very helpful, and a great starting point for me to search for more information. Thanks!